# logout doesn't work laravel jetstream, inertia+vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-jetstream, laravel-fortify

I try to build an app using laravel, jetstream and inertia+vue.js

every routes work fine except logout.

the original code provided by inertia in AppLayout.vue open a modal with 404 error - but the log out works :

```
<form @submit.prevent="logout">
    <JetDropdownLink as="button">
        Log Out
    </JetDropdownLink>
</form>
```

after some researches I tried another method which gives me this error : The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Log out does not work.

```
<form method="post">
    <JetDropdownLink as="button" type="submit" onclick="event.preventDefault(); this.closest('form').submit();">
        Logout
    </JetDropdownLink>
</form>
```

I tried some kind of mashup - It stays on the same page but a question mark appears at the end of the URL : https://website.fr/app/dashboard?

```
<form @submit.prevent="logout">
    <JetDropdownLink as="button" onclick="event.preventDefault(); this.closest('form').submit();">
        Logout
    </JetDropdownLink>
</form>
```

I have no idea of where the problem could be.

in the script at the top of the AppLayout.vue :

```
const logout = () => {
    Inertia.post(route('logout'));
};
```

the route in vendor/laravel/fortify/routes :

```
Route::post('/logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
        ->name('logout');
```

any help will be much appreciated

Comment: can you try ```php artisan route:list``` and show the output here? or just update your question with that output

Answer (score 1):

done: just had to add a route to redirect on login page after logout because logout was redirecting to / route

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return redirect()->route('login');
});
```